# Apple Touch Icon on Weebly

Tags: apple-touch-icon

I've read a lot about the Apple Touch icon, but i can't get this working on my Weebly site.

Does anyone know how to get it going?

I've tried everything.. nothing is working!

Comment: Please explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you've probably already figured this out, but I was having the same issue so I thought I'd post this for the benefit of all.

**Upload the icon**
To accomplish this you'll first need to upload your apple-touch-icon.png file. This is done in the **DESIGN** section of the Weebly editor. Click on DESIGN and look at the left menu panel. At the bottom is a button to "Edit HTML / CSS". Click that button. A new page will open. On that page's left menu panel, near the bottom, click on the button that reads **Add new file(s)**. Browse to your icon file to upload it.

**Add the link html**
Next, you need to add the html to your pages to link to the file. This can be done in the **PAGES** section of the Weebly editor. Select the page from the left menu panel, and click the **Advanced Settings +** link. Add your html to the **Header Code** section. Assuming your icon was named "apple-touch-icon.png", this is the html to add:

```
<LINK REL="apple-touch-icon" href="/files/theme/apple-touch-icon.png" />
```

The part I was having difficulty with was knowing what path to use in the href, since you don't get to see that when you upload the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your icon is 57 x 57?

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
```